# javascript event.target not working in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<script type ='javascript'>
    function fun(userID) {
        var btn = event.target; // error 'event' undefine in mozilla 
        alert(btn.id);
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<asp:linkButton id ="target" style =" cursor:pointer" onclick ="fun('1')" >click here </asp:LinkButton>
```

I am new in JavaScript, I have written above code and this code is working fine in Google chrome but not working in Mozilla Firefox. can anyone suggest how to find control firing event?

Comment: How is the function called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass event to the function:

```
<asp:linkButton id ="target" style =" cursor:pointer" onclick ="fun(event, '1')" >click here </asp:LinkButton>

function fun(event, userID)
{
    event= event|| window.event;
    var btn = event.target; 
    alert(btn.id);
}
```

OR

Make sure your event is not undefined

```
function fun(userID)
{
    var e = event || window.event;
    var btn = e.target; 
    alert(btn.id);
}
```

Comment: Firefox requires event as parameter, first one is perfect, make it cross browser by adding `e = event || window.event; var target=e.target || e.srcElement`.

Comment: A mix of both plus e.srcElement for ie is better or pass `this` instead

Comment: the first one works, the second one still have problems in firefox with event is undeifned

Answer (score 0):

If you 
pass the button using the keyword `this`  then no need for event

```
...onclick="fun(this,1)"

function fun(but, userID) { 
  var butID=but.id

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`event` is undefined in firefox, because firefox doesn't have this property and instead you can provides an event to an event handler function as  a parameter.

However your code is fine to work in Chrome and IE

Further I would also have script a type like `<script type ='text/javascript'>` and not just `<script type ='javascript'>`

Answer (score 0):

To access the `event` in the click handler, attach it in jQuery rather than in the HTML.

HTML:

```
<a id ="target" style ="cursor:pointer" data-value="1">click here</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#target").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var btn = this;
        var value = $(this).data('value');
        alert(btn.id + ', ' + value);
    });
});
```

Many (including myself) consider this the "proper" way to attach event handlers. There are several advantages, of which access to the event object is just one.

Comment: how to pass more than one argument to function . is i have to use split() function???

Comment: Yes, you can compact your data into one `data-value` and separate it out with `.split()`. Alternatively you can set any number of `data-xxx`, `data-yyy`, attributes in the HTML - each of them becomes individually accessible in jQuery with `$(this).data('xxx')`, `$(this).data('yyy')` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use arguments[0].target instead of event.target. Most browsers support the event global variable, but firefox does not. arguments[0] contains all the same properties and functions, but is supported by all browsers.

As a side note: indices in the arguments array can be changed by your own code. In my current project arguments[0] contains all of my controller functions for some reason, while the global event methods and properties are contained in arguments[1]. Not entirely sure why this is, but you might need to do some debugging on the arguments array to see what values it contains and adjust accordingly. More often than not however, arguments[0] should work.