# e = event || window.event; statement is not working properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript and jQuery so i have very silly doubt please bear with me

```
$(document).click(function () {
    alert("!");
    var e = event || window.event;  
    alert("!");
});
```

if i click on any part of the webpage then i should get two alerts with "!" as the text, it is working as expected in Chrome. In Firefox it is alerting only once

http://jsfiddle.net/Wu2Gh/8/

Comment: event is not defined, and jquery does that check for you so it is a waste anyway. Look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: check your JS console, you'll see error messages.

Comment: updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Wu2Gh/11/

Comment: @epascarello So wat should i do know which element was clicked. But i have read in other Stack overflow question that this statement should work in both firefox and chrome
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051936/javascript-event-target-not-working-in-mozilla

Comment: That check you would have to do if you were not using jQuery. It does that under the covers. It is as simple as `$(document).click(function (e) { console.log(e.target); });`

Answer (score 3):

Since you use jQuery, all you need to do is:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {

});
```

jQuery handles the browser differences and always passes an event object to the handler.

I recommend to read the [**jQuery tutorial about event handling**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `event` variable you are referring to. The Event object is the argument to the handler function. It should be

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    alert("!");
    var e = event || window.event;  
    alert("!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.you are not passing event parameter to function

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    alert("!");
    var e = event || window.event;  
     alert("!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error "event is not defined" why dont you get the event this way:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
  alert("!");
  var e = event || window.event;  
  alert("!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `event` is obviously undefined. So that line of code is causing a stop.
You need to send the event to the click function.

```
$(document).click(function(event){


});
```